# How to configure the keyboard to behave like Mac's?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, macintosh, gnome-shell

I am using Gnome (on Ubuntu 20.04) and I would like to configure that my PC keyboard behaves like Mac's: all UI keyboard shortcuts should use the key closest to the `space` key as its shortcut key (so instead of Mac's `command` key). This should hold in terminal emulator applications as well: `ctrl-c` should be done with the real `ctrl` key and send the interrupt, while `command-c` should copy to the clipboard.

I have achieved this by configuring keyboard options to:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl_lwin', 'ctrl:ralt_rctrl', 'ctrl:swap_rwin_rctl']"
```

This makes the bottom row of keys on my laptop keyboard to behave like, from left to right: `super`, `fn`, `alt`, `ctrl`, `space`, `ctrl`, `super`. This means that in all UI applications with default keyboard shortcuts pressing keys the closest to `space` behaves like Mac: it sends `ctrl-c` to copy the clipboard, for example.

In terminal emulator applications, the keyboard options I would need are a bit different:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "['altwin:swap_alt_win']"
```

This makes the keys from left to right be: `ctrl`, `fn`, `alt`, `super`, `space`, `super`, `ctrl`. This works great again. Pressing the most left bottom key works as expected, `ctrl-c` now sends the interrupt. And I can configure keyboard shortcuts so that pressing the key closest to the `space` together with `c` copies to the clipboard, again making it work like on Mac.

With this configuration I always press the same key on the keyboard to copy to the clipboard, and same key to send the interrupt.

Now, the question is how to configure so that:

- Only terminal emulation application windows have the second keyboard options.
- That all other windows, including the Gnome shell itself have the first keyboard options.
- That while terminal emulation application window is focused, global (system) shortcuts still work. For example, I have a shortcut that pressing `ctrl-f1` (which is using the key closest to the `space` for UI applications and Gnome shell) switches to the first workspace. Now while I am in terminal emulation application window this should continue to work.
- That keyboard options are combined with current language-based layout. So if I change the keyboard language through Gnome shell, options are combined based on the current application's window. I do not use per-application language layouts, but system wide. Also, I could live with having only one keyboard language in terminal emulation applications. But for other applications I do need and use multiple keyboard languages.